# Lebesgue measurable sets: $1 \in A-A$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset [-1, 1]$ Lebesgue measurable with $\lambda (A) > 1$. Why does it hold true that $1 \in A-A$, where $ A -A =$ {$x-y: x, y \in A$} ?

Comment: Better think of it as a pigeonhole principle for reals mod 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A\cap[0,1]-1$ and $A\cap[-1,0]$. By $\lambda(A)>1$, they must have non-empty intersection.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But why does follow from $\lambda(A) > 1$ that the intersection of the two guys is not empty?

Comment: Because $\lambda(A)= \lambda(A\cap[0,1]-1)+\lambda(A\cap[-1,0])$. And the two latter sets are subsets of $[-1,0]$, which has measure $1$. Two subsets of $[-1,0]$ with total measure greater than $1$ must have non-empty intersection.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Now it's clear. But why does then follow from this that $1 \in A-A$?

Comment: Consider what an overlap means. It means that there is some $y\in A\cap [-1,0]$ such that $y+1\in A\cap [0,1]$. Now subtract these two numbers from one another.

Comment: Alllll right, I got it. Thank you! :)